# Identity element

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am confused about the concept of identity element via ,If (S,*) is an algebraic structure where S={A: A is a 2x2 matrix having all entries a} and * is matrix multiplication (binary operation) then  this set have identity element E= [ 1/2    1/2
                      1/2    1/2] .why this is so it should be usual identity I .please guide me

Answer (score 1):

The identity element $E$ should fulfill that for all $A \in S$

$$
A \cdot E = E \cdot A = A
$$

Now with $E$ being

$$
E = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

We get for all $A \in S$

$$
A \cdot E = \begin{pmatrix}
a & a\\
a & a
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}a + \frac{1}{2}a  & \frac{1}{2}a + \frac{1}{2}a \\
\frac{1}{2}a + \frac{1}{2}a  & \frac{1}{2}a + \frac{1}{2}a 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
a & a\\
a & a
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

and similarly for $E \cdot A$

Comment: Yes but then A inverse also exists and  det(A) =0 then how can this possible for singular matrix

Comment: @user356861 You have specified a subset of the set of all two by two matrices. "Inverses" exist within the context you have specified.

Comment: So in this case A is invertible also isn't it?

Comment: Instead of calling it invertible, I'll call it E-invertible to emphasize that these are different concepts.  With the definition of E-invertible being very specifically that there exists an element $B$ such that $AB=BA=E$  (*note that this is different than the usual meaning of invertible in the usual space of matrices being $AB=BA=I$*), each matrix in your set *except for the zero matrix* will be "E-invertible."  $\begin{bmatrix}a&a\\a&a\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{4a}&\frac{1}{4a}\\\frac{1}{4a}&\frac{1}{4a}\end{bmatrix}$.  They will not be invertible in the usual sense however.

Comment: @user356861 Before you even ask, you seem interested in the concept of determinant as well here.  The usual definition of determinant will not be interesting for your specific set (*they all have determinant zero*), so you might be interested in asking about a sort of "E-determinant."  You may want to read about [functional determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_determinant) and see if you can apply any of what it has to say for your specific situation, otherwise you can make your own definition for E-determinants and explore its properties.  It isn't of much general interest.

Comment: So it means that in linear algebra we should specifically write about identity element otherwise that can make different sense

Comment: You should specifically write about what specific definitions you are using for identity,operation,inverse,etc... *if you are working in a context other than the usual one and the definitions might be different than normal*.  It is perfectly fine to not mention specific definitions if they happen to be the usual definitions that everyone should be familiar with already.  It would be incredibly tedious if every time we want to talk and discuss something we have to start from scratch and build definitions from the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

Within the set you have chosen the matrix with entries $a\in R$ (where $R$ is the system of numbers where $a$ lives - could be integers or reals etc) corresponds to multiplication by $2a$, so with $a=\frac 12$ you have the identity for the set of matrices you have defined with the operation you have specified.

The "normal" identity for matrix multiplication is not an element of this set.

Comment: So it means that I is the identity matrix only when set is consist of all mxn matrices and in linear algebra we only consider such matrices that's why we say in such cases that matrix is singular and Thus non invertible

Comment: @user356861 Here you have square matrices, so you can multiply on both sides. What is meant by "invertible" depends on context - the same object can be part of different structures. For example $1$ is not the identity element when you are adding integers, but is when you are multiplying them. Here it is because your matrices are singular and have the same subspace for their kernel that they work as they do - they have rank 1 and effectively act as scalars on the one dimensional subspace they don't send to zero.

Comment: Thanks Mark sir and I wanna know whether we can explore concept of determinant for those n square matrices which have identity matrix different from usual I ...say in above case when all elements are a and identity is [ 1/2  1/2  1/2  1/2] ...what about determinant